# Power bi query is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

Is it possible to select two tables from one database and one table from another database

Comment: What have you tried? Seems to be a lot of solutions [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=power+bi+query+two+databases)

Comment: Yes SELECT * From Table1 t INNER JOIN [Server2].[Database].dbo.Table2 t2 on t.Id = t2.Id

Comment: You will need to add [Server2] as a Linked Server under Properties of your Server -> Server Objects -> Linked Servers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when using import mode, there is no limit on the number and type of the data sources (make sure that **Import** radio button is selected):

[image]

Import the data from the first data source, then import the data from the second data source. After that you may want to review and define the relationships between the tables from the different data sources (by clicking on **Manage Relationships** button in the ribbon):

[image]

There is no limit on the data sources, so you can do this not only between two SQL Servers, but between SQL Server and flat file, or flat file and web source, etc. So there is no need to use linked servers at all.